# dropbox slow on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dropbox

My dropbox syncing is incredibly slow...
I am using dropbox from the ubuntu repository on an almost fresh ubuntu installation.

I would like to avoid to install the package from the dropbox website for the reasons explained here [Dropbox Upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512779/dropbox-upgrade)

Is someone having the same problem? How can I  solve?

EDIT :

This is an example of what I get.

```
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ dropbox status
Syncing (17 files remaining, 22 secs left)
Uploading 17 files (123.3 KB/sec, 22 secs left)
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ dropbox status
Syncing (17 files remaining, 3 mins left)
Uploading 17 files (13.2 KB/sec, 3 mins left)
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ dropbox status
Syncing (17 files remaining, 5 mins left)
Uploading 17 files (8.2 KB/sec, 5 mins left)
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ dropbox status
Syncing (17 files remaining)
Uploading 17 files...
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ dropbox status
Syncing (17 files remaining)
Uploading 17 files...
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$
```

EDIT: I have run `sudo dropbox update`  so I am probably using the last version of dropbox

EDIT:

```
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ apt-cache policy dropbox
dropbox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ 


donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ apt-cache policy nautilus-dropbox
nautilus-dropbox:
  Installed: 1.6.1-1
  Candidate: 1.6.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.6.1-1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
donbeo@donbeo-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$
```

EDIT: Without the need of any changes dropbox is now working well. I think that the problem has probably been solved with an update or something.

If someone is still having this problem and wants to know my version of dropbox or other details I am happy to help.

Comment: What is the speed of your internet connection (speedtest.net for ex.) is your internet only slow with dropbox syncing? How are you connected wireless or cable?

Comment: @LnxSlck my connection is fast  http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/3712690152    I am using wifi. Everything works very well and on a windows computer on the same wifi dropbox works well

Comment: Have you tried an older version of dropbox?

Comment: no how can I do that? can this be related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/512779/dropbox-upgrade   ?

Comment: What is the version of dropbox you are running now?

Comment: I have installed the version from the software center in ubuntu 14.04 .  I do not know how to check the version

Comment: Many people are having this problem. See http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=119245. Check a workaround here: http://askubuntu.com/a/515916/132444

Comment: without any changes dropbox now seems to be working. Let's see how does it go

Comment: Please do this: 'apt-cache policy dropbox' and tell me what version it is

Comment: @LnxSlck I have edited the question

Comment: Try to install an older version 'apt-get install nautilus-dropbox_1.6.0' or 'apt-get install nautilus-dropbox_1.4.0'

Comment: Please post the output of the following commands from a terminal - `dropbox status` , `dropbox running` , `dropbox start` , `dropbox ls` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was probably inside the dropbox server.  Now everything is working well with the dropbox version from the repository

Answer (score 2):

Other people are having this problem. Check [this thread](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=119245) in Dropbox forum.

[There is a workaround](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=119245&page=3&replies=89#post-625477) that worked for me that is using Dropbox through a proxy. I recommend a private proxy for security reasons.

Here are [instructions on how to setup a proxy using AWS](http://frankhq.io/blog/2012/11/14/how-to-setup-a-private-proxy-server-on-ec2-in-under-10-minutes/).
Then setup Dropbox to use the proxy and your files should start synching again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is almost a non practicable solution. I will wait a little bit for better solution before to accept this answer.

Comment: Your link to the Dropbox forum is 404ing. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but if you start Dropbox from the command line you get this message:

```
Unable to monitor entire Dropbox folder hierarchy. Please run 
"echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p" 
and restart Dropbox to fix the problem.
```

Following that message has fixed this same issue for me. More info here: https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/dropbox-sync-takes-ages-and-seems-to-be-stuck-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I think this answer deserves to be in a separate question of its own.  The question asker may not be  receiving such a message after all. So his problem may be different than the one faced by @Paul Feakins.

Comment: What do you think @Zanna

Comment: I think this answer is fine here and may help others @TejasShetty