# How to install Dropbox on Ubuntu 14.04 (October 2015)

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-center, dropbox

I make this **answered** question because it took me a while to find the right solution so I hope it helps somebody (I am a quite new to Linux so I was trying to use the "secure" way to do it):

- Dropbox has some kind of update/compatibility issues with ubuntu (or the other way around). Solutions that I see on forums from months and years ago do not work after some months (after reading the comments). **This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 on october 2015**
- Dropbox installed from the ubuntu software center won't work/start
- Downloaded .deb file from the dropbox website requires a daemon to be installed. After installing it, dropbox still does not work and gives a lot of error messages (about the daemon)

**Solution**: Just use the command line (terminal)

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

I found the command here: [Things To Do After Installing Ubuntu 14.04 - It's FOSS](http://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04/)

I found a detailed explanation on this issue on the answer of this question (hard to find if you don't know about the problematic update): [Dropbox Upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512779/)

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" into the title. Write an answer and accept your answer 24 hours later

Comment: how is this "Q" not different from this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126198/how-to-install-dropbox?rq=1

Comment: It is the same question but it is 3 years old and the person does not mention the ubuntu version. Like I mentioned, very often I find answers to similar questions that no longer work (due to Ubuntu updates or updates of the software/repositories in question). It gives the same command for terminal so I will select it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1.Download the installer from Official site ,([64 bit](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/ubuntu/dropbox_2015.02.12_amd64.deb) ,[32 bit](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/ubuntu/dropbox_2015.02.12_i386.deb))

2.Open terminal and run the following command:

For 32 bit:

```
 cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

For 64 bit:

```
 cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

then run,

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

- You can also install from Software Center

Or

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

then it will ask to restart all running instances of Nautilus,then run `nautilus --quit`

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

terminal commands for dropbox:

```
dropbox
```

---

```
status       get current status of the dropboxd
help         provide help
puburl       get public url of a file in your dropbox
stop         stop dropboxd
running      return whether dropbox is running
update       download latest version of dropbox
start        start dropboxd
filestatus   get current sync status of one or more files
ls           list directory contents with current sync status
autostart    automatically start dropbox at login
exclude      ignores/excludes a directory from syncing
lansync      enables or disables LAN sync
```

Comment: When I run `sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox` I get the error `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nautilus-dropbox : Depends: dropbox but it is not going to be installed`